# Salto de linea javascript

Tags: javascript, array

estoy intentando mostrar horarios que tengo en un array pero la idea es que se muestren uno debajo del otro y no lo estoy logrando. Los elementos los traigo separados por *. Si alguien me puede ayudar a ver què estoy haciendo mal se lo agradeceria.

```js
 horario_proximo_origen ="11:37:00*11:38:00*11:39:00*11:40:00*11:41:00";
 array_horario_proximo_origen= horario_proximo_origen.split('*');
  cantidad_horario_proximo = array_horario_proximo_origen.length;


 document.getElementById("titulo_horario_proximo_origen").text= "Prox. horarios "+result.linea_origen+", parada "+result.nombre_origen_directo;

 for (i=0; i<=cantidad_horario_proximo; i++){

document.getElementById("horario_proximo_origen").text= array_horario_proximo_origen;
 
  }
```

```html
 <div id ="proximos_horarios" style ="visibility:block; width:100%;">
 
 <a id= "titulo_horario_proximo_origen" href="#" style = " background-color: #86CE18;color:#FFF;  width:100%"></a><br>
  
  
  <a id= "horario_proximo_origen" href="#" style = "color:#000;"></a>


<br><br>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta que da @[David](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/267509/128321) es una muy buena aproximación a la solución del problema, aquí te dejo otra solución alternativa usando *[String Templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings)*, he sustituido el `innerText` del cuerpo del horario por `innerHTML`.

He dado un valor a `result`, para evitar un error de ejecución.

He separado cada variable en una constante y he dado los valores de los cuerpos usando *String Templates*, en el caso del cuerpo se hace un join de los valores devueltos por el map con la cadena 
 y así tienes el salto de línea.

```js
/* Doy un valor al objeto result porque si no da error de ejecución al no estar definido en tu código inicial */

const result = {
  linea_origen: 'Sevilla',
  nombre_origen_directo: 'Madrid',
}

/* Los datos con los que vamos a trabajar */
const horario_proximo_origen = '11:37:00*11:38:00*11:39:00*11:40:00*11:41:00';
const array_horario_proximo_origen = horario_proximo_origen.split('*');

/* Separamos los selectores de los elementos, quizá más adelante querramos hacer más cosas con ellos aparte de modificar su contenido */
const scheduleTitle = document.getElementById("titulo_horario_proximo_origen");
const scheduleBody = document.getElementById('horario_proximo_origen');

/* Llenamos el Título del Horario */
scheduleTitle.innerText = `Próx. horarios ${result.linea_origen}, parada ${result.nombre_origen_directo}`;

/* Llenamos el Contenido del Horario iterando sobre array_horario_proximo_origen y uniéndolo con la cadena <br> (salto de línea)*/
scheduleBody.innerHTML = `${array_horario_proximo_origen.map(time => `${time}`).join('<br>')}`
```

```html
<div id ="proximos_horarios" style ="visibility:block; width:100%;">
    <a id= "titulo_horario_proximo_origen" href="#" style = " background-color: #86CE18;color:#FFF;  width:100%"></a><br>
    <a id= "horario_proximo_origen" href="#" style = "color:#000;"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Te he optimizado un poco el código para hacerlo más legible. Con el siguiente código te debería de funcionar. He utilizado la propiedad `innerHTML` en lugar de `text` para poder añadir párrafos, los cuales son display block por defecto y automáticamente ocuparán una nueva linea cada uno. Esto es más eficiente que utilizar los `<br>`

```js
horario_proximo_origen = "11:37:00*11:38:00*11:39:00*11:40:00*11:41:00";

let array_horario_proximo_origen = [];
array_horario_proximo_origen = horario_proximo_origen.split('*');

let titulo = document.getElementById("titulo_horario_proximo_origen");
let horarios = document.getElementById("horario_proximo_origen");

titulo.innerHTML = "<p> Prox. horarios "+result.linea_origen+", parada "+result.nombre_origen_directo+"</p>;

array_horario_proximo_origen.forEach(function(i){
  horarios.innerHTML += "<p>" + i + "</p>";
})
```

```html
<div id ="proximos_horarios" style ="visibility:block; width:100%;">
 
 <a id= "titulo_horario_proximo_origen" href="#" style = " background-color: #86CE18;color:#FFF;  width:100%"></a><br>
  
  
  <a id= "horario_proximo_origen" href="#" style = "color:#000;"></a>


<br><br>
 </div>
```

Comment: ¿No sería mejor usar `Array.forEach`? Al no dar valor de retorno a `Array.map` parece un mal uso de este método.

Comment: tienes razón, ahora estaría correcto